# Noob help; setting up Android environment

Tags: android, sdk, installation

Trying to install jdk-6u31-windows-i586 and eclipse-java-galileo-SR2-win32 and android-sdk_r17-windows
When trying to add the

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Android Development Tools 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853)
>     Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0' but it could not be found

Answer (score 2):

From the [ADT plugin site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes):

> ADT 17 - Dependencies: [..] Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6.2) or higher is required for ADT 17.0.0.

Eclipse Galileo is too old and not supported. Pick a newer version *(Indigo, which is the newest, works fine for me)*.

Comment: Many, many thanks to both answers! I finally have it installed. Now to learn how to use!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 3.6 is Helios, whereas Eclipse 3.5 is Galileo; it would appear that the version of ADT you're installing needs 3.6 or later. 3.7 is stable now.

Comment: Many, many thanks to both answers! I finally have it installed. Now to learn how to use!